# How do I find a specific case in Delaware?

Tags: united-states, legal-research, court-records, delaware

I've been reading about a [patent case between BT and Valve Corp](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-37242696).

From my reading I've found this complaint: https://search.rpxcorp.com/litigation_documents/12085257

I'd like to know more about this case (has it gone to trial yet, transcripts if any, etc.).

I've been trying to search for the case [here](https://courtconnect.courts.delaware.gov/public/ck_public_qry_main.cp_main_idx), the official search page for Delaware cases and judgments. But searching for "Valve" or "British Telecommunications" have not turned up any results.

If this isn't the right way to research this case then what would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a federal court case, not one in the Delaware courts.

You could find the case by setting up an account with the PACER system and searching using the parties or the case number and the court was the action was pending. PACER is a publicly available database of all federal court documents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but it looks like we've got the case in the RECAP Archive, here: https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/4221177/british-telecommunications-plc-v-valve-corporation/

As @ohwileke says, this is a federal case, so it's going to be in PACER. We maintain the RECAP Archive that has a mirror of a lot of what's in PACER, especially things that are in the news.